# Python functions and lists, where do they need to be?

Tags: python, list, append, indentation

Fairly new to Python, so this may be basic but help is greatly appreciated. I'm using Python to call my Tableau server API, and attempting to cycle through each user in a group and build a list of email addresses with the goal of emailing each group a pdf of their views. I've defined the lists I need outside of all functions (this is referred to as globally, I think?). In the code sample below, I'm appending 'testuser' to the list as I don't expect the preceding loop to work initially. I'm just trying to establish that data will append to the globally defined list. It does not. When I print the list in my main function, it's empty.

```
xmlns = {'t': 'http://tableau.com/api'}    
groupnames = ['Data Source Publisher']
workbooks = []
usernames = []

def get_email_address(groupname):
    groups = server_response.findall('.//t:group', namespaces=xmlns)
    for group in groups:
        if group.get('name') == groupname:
            usernames.append(group.get('id'))

    usernames.append('2002327')
    return usernames;

def main():
    print(usernames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is my major malfunction here?

Comment: Are you actually calling `get_email_address` at any point? Also, make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation; in your last code block, your first two `print` calls are indented with spaces, but the last one is indented with a tab. Mixing characters like that can cause the interpreter to interpret your code in surprising and confusing ways.

Comment: What is `groupname`? It's not defined. The closest is `groupnames` which is actually a list. But I think you want to compare strings?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kevin, I'm not calling get_email_address in the main, so that explains why no data is being appended. The space vs. tab thing is something I did on the forum. They're all tabs in my source file.

Comment: Your assumptions about scope are correct. A variable defined outside of all functions is Global. And appending to a Global list from within a function, will modify the Global function. But you do have to call the function at some point.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I do want to compare strings. groupname is an argument in the get_email_address function and groupnames is the list of strings I want to use as an argument. So I will update them to match.  I'm guessing that using a list  as an argument to a function will not work?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could just create a small, self-contained example so that we can review it. I understand your approach to breaking it down with small descriptions between each bit of code, but the whole example need not be much longer than you posted before, and everyone here looks at, and makes sense of, code all day :) You can edit the question to include it.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not sure how much additional code is needed, so I've perhaps added too much. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please see the link from @juanpa.arrivillaga. We just need a minimal snippet that illustrates your problem, it doesn't even have to be your actual code. Your example doesn't show how this code starts off (I assume `main` controls the flow, but you never call it). Please reduce it down to something that just illustrates your confusion with namespace.

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, I understand. I think I've eliminated everything not relevant to the initial problem.

Comment: It's looking a lot better now :) I'll take a look.

Comment: `main()` does not call `get_email_address(groupname)` so that code never runs. Is this representative of what you have?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, that does seem to be the problem. That is why 'testuser' is never appended to usernames.

Comment: Thank you for responding to the feedback concerning your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that you are not updating a global variable. The problem is that you do not call `get_email_address` at any point in your code.

1. I cannot run `groups = server_response.findall('.//t:group', namespaces=xmlns)` so I have to make a guess at the structure it returns
2. I called `get_email_address` with an argument that I knew would fail to get a match in `if group.get('name') == groupname:` so that your default `append` after that check would still fire.

This does what you expect:

```
xmlns = {'t': 'http://tableau.com/api'}    
groupnames = ['Data Source Publisher']
workbooks = []
usernames = []

def get_email_address(groupname):
    groups = [{'name': 'abc', 'id': '789'}, {'name': '123', 'id': '678'}] # I assume this is representative
    for group in groups:
        if group.get('name') == groupname:
            usernames.append(group.get('id'))

    usernames.append('2002327')
    return usernames

def main():
    get_email_address('something') # Call the function
    print(usernames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you change `get_email_address('something')` to `get_email_address('abc')` then you will note that your printed global list contains two items (since it will find a match in `groups`).